# Parent-Child relation using wait()-sleep() function call

Tags: c

Could anyone please help me to understand the flow of the below code:

```
    /* Child Process creation using fork() */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

main(){
    int i=0;
    pid_t chp1,chp2,chp3;
chp1=fork();
if(chp1<0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Child creation failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
else if(chp1==0){
    printf("Inside Child Process1,process id is %d\n", getpid());
    printf("Value of i in Child process1 is %d\n", i);
    i=i++;
    printf("Value of i in child process1 after increment is %d\n", i);
    sleep(10);
}
else{
    chp2=fork();
    if(chp2==0){
        sleep(30);
        printf("Inside Child Process2,process id is %d\n", getpid());
        printf("Value of i in Child process2 is %d\n", i);
        i=i+2;
        printf("Value of i in child process2 after increment is %d\n", i);
        sleep(40);
    }
    else{
        wait(chp2);
        printf("Inside Parent Process, value of pid1=%d pid2=%d\n", chp1,chp2);
        printf("Value of i in Parent process is %d\n", i);
        i=i+5;
        printf("Value of i in Parent process, after increment is %d\n", i);
        wait(chp1);
    }
    }

printf("Common Section, Value of i=%d\n", i);
}
```

### ---> the behaviour of the output should be like this:

1. First Child1(chp1) will execute its printf parts and also finish its execution.
2. Then Child2(chp2) will execute its printf parts and also finish its execution.
3. Then at last, parent process will execute its printf parts(as there is wait(chp2) before its printf parts, so it will wait for the execution of child2) and will finish its execution.

But, in output, I can see that

1. First Child1(chp1) will execute its printf parts and also finish its execution.
2. Parent process is executing its printf parts and then wait for child2.
3. Child2 completes its execution.
4. Parent completes its execution.

### **Below is the output:**

```
[Rajim@rajim OS_Prog]$ ./a.out
Inside Child Process1,process id is 3291
Value of i in Child process1 is 0
Value of i in child process1 after increment is 1
Common Section, Value of i=1
Inside Parent Process, value of pid1=3291 pid2=3292 pid3=8605684
Value of i in Parent process is 0
Value of i in Parent process, after increment is 5
Inside Child Process2,process id is 3292
Value of i in Child process2 is 0
Value of i in child process2 after increment is 2
Common Section, Value of i=2
Common Section, Value of i=5

[Rajim@rajim OS_Prog]$
```

So could anyone please make me understand how the program is flowing?

Comment: What specifically you don't understand or think unexpected?

Comment: @Blue Moon ... in the parent process part, I have called the wait(chp2). So it should wait for the completion of the child process2. Then after it sud print its printfs. But it's not happening. So I want to know what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `wait()` is wrong. [**wait()**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) doesn't accept PID of the child argument (in single argument form), rather a pointer to an int to store the status.

Change the call to:

```
   else{
      int status;
      wait(&status);
      ...
```

Remember that `wait` returns on a status change from *any* process. If you specifically want to wait for a process you should use `waitpid()`:

```
 else{
   int status;
   waitpid(chp2, &status, 0);
```

Also, the line in the first child:

```
i=i++;
```

invokes [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C.

Comment: there is another form wait() that takes arguments, one of which is process id ... as I want to wait for a particular child process, I have used the below syntax:

    wait(chp2,&status,0);

but then also I am getting the same result.

Comment: hmm..I can't reproduce that. Did you check the 2nd call to fork() succeeded?

Comment: Check the return codes of all calls such as fork(), wait() etc. I don't see any reason for it not work as expected using waitpid().

Comment: now it's working using waitpid as 
    waitpid(chp2,&status,0);

Thanks for ur help ....

Answer (score 0):

To match your expected flow, you need to `wait` for ch1 before forking ch2. ch1 and the parent will run in parallell and there's no telling which one gets to execute first. Thus your checkpoint will have to be to let the parent continue executing after ch1 has exited.

Comment: Why does not reaping first child have any impact on the other?

Comment: It's to block the parent from forking the second child before the first one exits. Sure, the sleeps help, but I think they're a workaround for solving the problem properly.

Comment: Why does parent have to wait/block for the first child to complete before forking another? Parent waits only for the 2nd child using 2nd child's pid.

Comment: That's the only way to guarantee that the first child will output before the second one. Otherwise flow might theoretically go fork(child1) => parent continues => fork(child2) => child 2 prints.

Comment: I don't think OP's concerned about 1st child's output. Look at his example output: parent process is printing output *before* child2 done with its output. If reaping child2 works as expected then that can't happen.

Comment: Reaping child 1 first arguably still the most simple solution. It avoid the ambiguity of what child will be reaped when.And the question is more or less "how do I make the code match the expected output". Using sleep will not guarantee that, and is bad practice. Since this looks like homework I don't think OP should learn to use bad practices.

Comment: sleep is bad practice or not is beside the point. Read the comment by OP in the question. There's no ambiguity when reaping a process by its PID.

Comment: Well we interpreted the question differently, and thus answered different things. I think neither answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks both of u @BlueMoon and PerJohansson for ur valuable discussion ... I just wanted to test the parent-child synchronization using wait() function call by the process id. So my intention is to fork multiple child from a parent and the parent would wait for some particular children only not for all as in case of wait(NULL) call .... now the code is working fine with waitpid() call .... once again thanks both of u ... :)